# How do I add Custom text or URL links to FB Registration XFBML?

Tags: facebook, xfbml

OK I have been looking all over the place for ways to add URL links to FB Registration XFBML but with no success. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ As you can see at the bottom left their are the links call Terms of Service,Privacy Policy in the examples that FB give of the Registration Form. How do I add text like that inside my own fb XFBML?? I need it because I need something that says by Clicking Register you agree with our terms and Policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are already a Facebook Developer and have created an App...

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Select which app you want to edit on the left pane
3. Click "**Edit app**" in the top right corner
4. In the left pane, go to **Settings->Advanced**
5. At the bottom of the page there should be fields to provide URLs for your Privacy Policy and Terms of Use. Type in your URLs there and they should automatically appear at the bottom of your Facebook registration page as in the examples on the page you provided (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration)